# Spring Security always returns 403 forbidden in Postman

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to configure Spring Security authorization but I'm getting 403 (forbidden) for each Postman request.

I checked the other questions but nothing works. Can anyone who got this problem and resolved it share what I need to do to fix it?

I want to add an authorization to make `/authenticate` accessible for all users, `/registeradmin`, `/registersimpleuser` and `/listallusers`  only for the admin role.

I'm getting 403 even in `/authenticate` which is configured as permit all.

Spring Security config class:

```java
package com.project.encheres.security.configuration;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;
import com.project.encheres.repository.UserRepository;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Component
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final UserRepository userRepo;
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    public SecurityConfiguration(UserRepository userRepo) {
        this.userRepo = userRepo;
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws     Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());       
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {  
        http
            .httpBasic()
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "localhost:8070/user/registersimpleuser").permitAll();
        http
            .httpBasic()    
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "localhost:8070/authenticate").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "localhost:8070/user/listallusers").hasAuthority("ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    public BCryptPasswordEncoder gePasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I already did that and I put /authenticate directly, but it doesn't work ,even for the other paths

Comment: already googled it i added .httpBasic().and().csrf().disable(); but it idnt work, also im totally new to spring

Comment: hasRole() method automatically adds the prefix "ROLE_". Since you are using hasAuthority(), I think you should explicitly add the prefix (i.e.) hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"). The comment is valid only in the case you are using the default naming convention of spring.

Comment: Add `logging.level.org.springframework.security` in your `application.properties` and post the stacktrace

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .httpBasic()
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "localhost:8070/user/registersimpleuser").permitAll();
    http
        .httpBasic()
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "localhost:8070/authenticate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "localhost:8070/user/listallusers").hasAuthority("ADMIN");
    http
        .csrf().disable();
}
```

Just added `http.csrf().disable();` in the end of the method.

[this will describe why your code was not working earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51088555/6821605)

Comment: added http.csrf ().disable() but still the same

Comment: @taruk You also have to remove `localhost:8070` from your configuration.

Comment: it works when postman get nothing on response with 403 code